# jQuery UI Autocomplete GET change

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have problem with jQuery UI Autocomplete. In my platform url islike this:

> mysystem/module/action/cash/param/value

but in jQuery Autocomplete, when I set source: "search", urlis like:

> mysystem/module/action/search?term=aza

so I want to change to my url format (mayby small change liberary jQuery Autocomplete) or delete GET method and send data POST method.

Thanks, I fix it:

> source: function(req, resp) {
>               $.getJSON(link_ajax +"/term/" +encodeURIComponent(req.term));
>           }

Answer (score 1):

See the [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option. You can use the function version to control exactly what the request looks like:

```
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mysystem/module/action/search/' + encodeURIComponent(request.term),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            //note - you may need to translate the data into a format the plugin can use
            response(data);
        }
    });
}
```